# Real time page update

Tags: php, javascript, real-time

I need help, This is what am actually trying to do. I have two files. "index.php" and "realtime.php" the index.php displays news from a particular country base on the url parameter "country_code", and the realtime.php updates the news list every 2 seconds. what I want is for realtime.php to get the current url parameter of index.php so that it can only update news from that particular country base on the url parameter. I really need this help. Thank you again.
script for index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.arte({'ajax_url': '../realtime.php?lastid='+$('.postitem:first').attr('id'), 'on_success': update_field, 'time': 1000}).start();
    function update_field(data)
    {
        $("#realtimeupdate").html(data);
    }
});

</script>
```

and script for realtime.php

```
<?php

include"customDB.php";
$lastid = $_REQUEST['lastid'];
$query = 'SELECT count(*) as newpost FROM wp_posts WHERE country_code = "XXXXX" AND   post_id > "'.$lastid.'"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rec = mysql_fetch_object($result);
if($rec->newpost){ ?>
<a href="" id="newpostlink">(<?php echo $rec->newpost; ?>) new posts</a>
<script type="text/javascript">document.title = '(<?php echo $rec->newpost; ?>) new posts'</script>
<?php } ?>
```

I want the value of country_code ="XXXXXX" in raltime.php to be the url parameter value of index.php
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you remove realtime.php from the app and instead push the updates to the connected web clients when more news become available? There are a whole host of [realtime web technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) that make this easy to do as well as removing the potentially very heavy resource load from your servers.

Comment: please can you explain a bit better of what you are saying

Comment: It's possible to push updates from a web server to a web client instead of using inefficient polling techniques. If you poll realtime.php every 2 seconds and have a reasonable number of connected clients you will be putting your web server under a lot of load. I suggest reading up on [Push Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). You can see a really [simple demo of push notifications using PHP here](http://j.mp/html5-php-push-frames).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Accessing query string in Javascript

First, you'll need to get the value of "country_code" that has been passed as a query string parameter. You can use Javascript like this to do so:

```
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
    var e,
        a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
        q = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (e = r.exec(q))
       urlParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
})();
```

(taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript))

Now, urlParams will look something like:

```
urlParams = {
    country_code: 'US'
}
```

So, you can change your AJAX call to add this parameter:

```
$.arte({'ajax_url': '../realtime.php?country_code='+urlParams.country_code+'lastid='+$('.postitem:first').attr('id'), 'on_success': update_field, 'time': 1000}).start();
```

And now it will be available via PHP under `$_GET['country_code']`.

### Using the variable in PHP

Now you can access the variable and use it in your query.

```
$country_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['country_code']);
$query = 'SELECT count(*) as newpost FROM wp_posts WHERE country_code = "' . $country_code . '" AND   post_id > "'.$lastid.'"';
```

Note that I've written this code to conform to your existing coding style. It's not very clean, so you might consider cleaning it up by using helpers like `$.param()` and MySQLi prepared statements.

Comment: thanks, i try your suggestion and i get this error,  <br />
Notice: Undefined index: lastid in C:\wamp\www\1afribari\realtime.php on line 5

Comment: So set $lastid. I copied it right out of your example code :P

Answer (score 1):

At page generation you can echo country code from $_GET['country_code'] to the script that calls `realtime.php`.

Or, alternatively, on `index.php` you can get your country parameter from `window.location` property and then pass it as a parameter to `realtime.php`.

Comment: Or he could echo $_GET['country_code'] and not have to bother with parsing window.location.

Comment: will be happy if you could show me how to do that. thanks for your responds

Comment: In the other example it's pretty well laid out.

Comment: am a novice and don't really know how to customize the examples i have been giving. any help will be greatly depreciated Thanks

Comment: your suggestion and the suggestion from "Interrobang"